# Greek characters get corrupted when returned as part of XML element in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns XML using the following piece of code:

```sql
DECLARE @error1 XML, @error2 XML

SET @error1 = 
(
    SELECT 1 AS '@Code', 
           CAST(Ν'My message in Greek' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Greek_CI_AS AS '@Message'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Employee)  
    FOR XML PATH ('Error')
)

SET @error2 = 
(
   ... Similar query here
)

IF (@error1 IS NOT NULL) OR (@error2 IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
      SELECT @error1, @error2
      FOR XML PATH('Errors'))
   RETURN
END
```

I use the following piece of code on the client-side to read the message:

```
XElement xe = null;
using (SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("usp_MyProc", connection))
{
   cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   using (XmlReader xmlReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteXmlReader())
   {
      xe = XElement.Load(xmlReader);
   }
}

if (xe != null)
{
    lblResults.Text = xe.Descendants("Error")
                        .Where(x => (int)x.Attribute("Code") == 1)
                        .FirstOrDefault()
                        .Attribute("Message")
                        .Value;
}
```

Unfortunately `lblResults.Text` is set to sth like `'���  ???????? ????'`. Any ideas on what is the cause of the issue and how it could be resolved?

**Edit:**

I managed to track down the source of the error. My proc is contained in a 'SQL Server Database Project' I've created in Visual Studio. The problem is caused when the project is *published* to SQL Server. Any hard-coded Greek characters inside the stored procedure are corrupted when uploaded to the server.

This is how the project looks like in Visual Studio:

[image]

The picture below displays the publish profile configuration

[image]

Comment: Silly question - did you forget the leading `N`? `N'My big fat greek message here'`

Comment: Giorgos, your last edit added the `N`. This did not solve the issue?

Comment: Όχι δεν χαλάνε. Only if you load them as *ASCII* do you get conversion errors. The data was lost (that's what happened) when you *loaded* the data. The mix between `?` and the actual Unicode replacement character `�` means that some of the data was mangled using an OLEDB source, some using .NET or another source that uses `�` instead of `?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is not a problem with the data stored in the database. The problem is in the hard-coded Greek characters inside the proc. Everything, even comments, gets corrupted after the project is published to the server. I can work-around the problem by manually deploying the proc on the Server, but I would like to avoid this, if possible,

Comment: `Any hard-coded Greek characters inside the stored procedure are corrupted when uploaded to the server.` That means your *code* is ASCII. Either the files are saved as ASCII instead of UTF8 and/or the string literals are ASCII, eg `'Κάποιο όνομα'` is an ASCII string literal which SQL Server *has* to translate to Unicode using the server's collation, while `N'Κάποιο όνομα'` is a Unicode string literal.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos TLDR [Ο Sql Server ΔΕΝ ΧΡΕΙΑΖΕΤΑΙ κόλπα για να υποστηρίξει τα ελληνικά](https://www.dotnetzone.gr/cs/blogs/pkanavos/archive/2007/01/18/23726.aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, that was it. I opened to proc code in Notepad and saved it as UTF-8. The proc is now published correctly. You can place your comment as an answer if you like, and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It might be enough to place an `N` before your literal:

```
CAST(N'My message in Greek' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) COLLATE Greek_CI_AS
```

Try this:

```
SELECT  'αλφάβητο' WithoutTheN
      ,N'αλφάβητο' WithN
```

Depending on the `COLLATION` the first expression will return more or less dirty: With my default I get

```
a?f?ß?t?    αλφάβητο
```

### UPDATE

The last edit in OP did add the `N`.

But - if there's nothing else involved - I do not see any other reason, why this should get wrong. XML is - in any case! - `NVARCHAR` under the hood and `C#` uses `unicode` for strings in any case. Nowhere in between there's any place, where this is changing.

Might be, that the `OUTPUT` of the SP `usp_MyProc` is declared as `VARCHAR`...

Comment: Ha! I was faster :-) +1

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah, by about 10 seconds... Have to type faster the next time :-)

Comment: Anyway it seems like Giorgos only forgot that in the question - it's edited in now, so it's probably a different matter...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yeah, I've just discovered this myself... See my update